# Lagrange Multipliers with Three constraints .

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

Let $J$ be the Functional $ J:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a Banach space of functions,

I would Like to minimize this functional under three constraint $F_1,F_2$ and $F_3$ such that  $ F_i:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \;$ **are linear** For $i=1,2,3$

To be more precise:

$\underset{u\in X}{\min} J(u)\quad$  subject to $\;F_1(u)=0, F_2(u)\leq 0$ and $F_3(u)\leq0$

I would like to use the **Lagrange multiplier** but the Problem is that as all the constraints are Linear so **the defferential** $dF_{1}(u), dF_{2}(u)$  and $dF_{3}(u)$ **are not linearly independant in** $X^{'}$

What can I do in this situation ?
Thank You in advance 
comments and references are welcome